# builtins.TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python

```
def printsection1(animals, station1, station2):
    animals=['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
    station1={'a04': 5, 'a05': 1, 'a03': 6, 'a01': 2}
    station2={'a04': 5, 'a02': 3, 'a03': 4, 'a01': 1}    

    print('Number of times each animal visited each station :')
    print('Animal Id'+' '*11+'Station 1'+' '*11+'Station 2'+'           ')

    #preparing animal station1 and station2
    for name in animals:
        if name in station1:
            visit=str(station1.get(name))
        else:
            visit=0
        if name in station2:
            visit2=str(station2.get(name))
        else:
            visit2=0

        space=str((20-len(visit))*' ')


        print(name+' '*17+str(visit)+space+str(visit2))
    print('='*60)
```

Actual output,output i am getting:

```
Animal Id           Station 1           Station 2           
a01                 2                   1
```

Error:

```
builtins.TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Wanted output:

```
Number of times each animal visited each station :
Animal Id           Station 1           Station 2           
a01                 2                   1                  
a02                 0                   3                  
a03                 6                   4                  
a04                 5                   5                  
a05                 1                   0                  
============================================================
```

Hey guys I was doing this program but am stuck at this point. I am trying to print animal Id and both stations. All three stations are 20 characters long but I keep getting this error for some reason.

Hope you guys can help :)

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `visit=0` is getting you.  The length of an integer is not defined, so `len(visit)` later on in your code is giving you an error.  It looks like you are setting `visit` to a string earlier in your code, so using `visit="0"` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `visit=0` visit will be an integer and then you can't make `space=str((20-len(visit))*' ')`, you can try writing `visit='0'`